# Replace string and find value in column in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, findstr

I have file like below, I need to find out that if any employee is "absent OR unknown" or late more than 1 min in both time column.

```
Col1          col2        col3     HH MM SS        HH MM SS 
sales       Present     George     01:02:00        04:05:00
sales       absent      Linda      00:00:03        00:00:00
Marketing   unknown     James      00:00:00        00:00:00
```

I am successful to remove ":" but not sure how to put if condition piping echo

```
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%files%) do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "line=!line::= !" 
      echo(!line!  
       endlocal
    ))
```

trying to get output like

```
George is more than 1 hr and 2 min late
Linda is absent
```

Any help is Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, are you on a windows desktop? Is powershell available on your machine?

Comment: jonyt, the content you have posted is not accurate, it is neither, fixed width or tab separated. Please revisit your question, and replace that content with an actual representation, by opening the file in notepad, and copy/pasting it directly.

Comment: @houstonrahoyt - Hi , No we are not allowed to use powershell on Machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "filename1=q72007068.txt"

(
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%e IN (%filename1%) DO (
 SET "reason="
 set "outfile=absorunk"
 FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
  FOR %%o IN (absent unknown) DO IF %%o==%%y SET "reason=%%o"
  FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=:" %%u IN ("%%y") DO (
   IF "%%w"=="" (
    SET "person=%%y" 
    ) ELSE (
     SET /a late=1%%u%%v%%w
     IF NOT DEFINED reason IF !late! gtr 1000100 SET "reason=late %%u:%%v:%%w"&set "outfile=late"
    )
  )
 )
 IF DEFINED reason ECHO !person! is !reason!>>"report_!outfile!.txt"
)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

`%%e` receives each full line, skipping the first, from the file.

`reason` is used as a flag to record the reason the report line is being generated - if it is generated.

`%%y` receives each element of the line in turn.

If an element is exactly `absent` or `unknown`, set `reason` to that value.

Attempt to tokenise the element into `%%u`..`%%w` using `:` as a delimiter.

If `%%w` is not set, then this is not a *time* element, so `person` will be set to the element value and hence will contain the element before the first *time*
element, which is the person's name.

If `%%w` is set, form hh:mm:ss as 1hhmmss which is a decimal number which does not have a leading `0`. Compare that against `1000100` which is 1 minute calculated on the same basis. if greater, then set `reason` to "late + the actual time-late.

If, after processing all of the elements, `reason` has been set then produce a report line detailing the person and reason.

I'll leave the formatting of the time as an exercise for those interested.

--- amended

in the light of the comment, reports sent to `report_absorunk.txt` for absent or unknown and `report_late.txt` for late.

Note that data will be appended to the report files should they already exist. The variable `outfile` is simply initialised to `absorunk` for each line and changed to `late` if the `reason` generated is `late`. Since `reason` is only defined if there is a reason to report the current data line, lines that are not reported still remain unreported.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for answering, It worked. Is there a way I can send output in separate files. first)  for people who are running late and second) for people who are absent or unknown, including person name in the files like "xyz person is absent "   and "abc person is 07 Min late"